# Failed to write metabase key

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, iis-7.5, application-pools, metabase

I'm running IIS7.5 on Windows 7, and it's got IIS6 Compatibility installed due to requirements from our current product installer.

After successfully installing our product, I realized I needed to reinstall some other software that it relies on.  I uninstalled our product, reinstalled the dependency product, and tried to reinstall our product.   Our MSI failed with  "`Failed to write data to metabase key. (-2147023584 /LM/W3SVC/1/<app name> )`".  The MSI log shows

```
Error 26104. Failed to write data to metabase key.  
(-2147024713   /LM/W3SVC/1/Root/<app name>)
```

Googling this problem doesn't help much.  Does anyone know how I can fix it?  Is it permissions related?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have the domain user account in the local admingroup?

Comment: Oh, yeah I should have mentioned, I'm in the admin group, and I'm running the MSI from a command prompt as administrator.

Comment: Do you have Anonymous Access and Windows Integrated enabled in Default Website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, I finally solved it.  I hope this helps someone else out.

It came down to the "other software" that our stuff relies on, in this case, ArcGIS Server.  The uninstall/reinstall of it somehow managed to leave duplicate  entries on multiple paths in the applicationHost.config file for IIS.

There were four entries:

```
<add name="ESRI_mapHandler" path="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.MapHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.MapHandler, ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls, Version=9.3.1.3000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" preCondition="integratedMode" />
<add name="ESRI_tileHandler" path="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer.TileHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer.TileHandler, ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer, Version=9.3.1.3000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" preCondition="integratedMode" />
<add name="ESRI_mime" path="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.MimeImage.ashx" verb="*" type="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.ImageHandler, ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web, Version=9.3.1.3000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" preCondition="integratedMode" />
<add name="ESRI_mime91" path="ESRI.Web.Controls.MIMEImage.aspx" verb="*" type="ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.WebControls.ImageHandler, ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.WebControls, Version=9.3.1.3000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

These entries were duplicated in the

```
 <location path="Default Web Site">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
```

and the

```
 <location path="" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
```

paths of the config file.  Removing the four entries under the Default Web Site path solved multiple issues!

I guess IIS was attempting a metabase write, but because the config file was bad, it just wasn't happening in certain cases.